# Is there a way in VBA to know about variables that aren't being used?

Tags: vba, excel, variables, vbe

Is there a tool, method or setting in the standard VBA Editor to warn about variables that have been `Dim`'med, but aren't being used?

Comment: I'm not convinced this question should have been put on-hold; the close reason states that _"[the question is] asking us to recommend [...] a tool [...] or other off-site resource"_. In fact the question is aimed at tools within the MS-Excel built in editor (VBE), not asking for a 3rd party tool or off-site resource. Although some options supplied in the answers rely on 3rd party tools, I don't think that necessarily makes them _"opinionated answers"_ or _"spam"_. Indeed [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43231349) I gave works directly in the VBE without any additional tools.

Comment: This is an excellent question. Reopen it please.

Comment: @ExcelHero, Done for now. This question wasn't about searching for tools, even if that came up to be the best answer. I was hoping for an internal VBA editor method.

Comment: I wish there were a way. You can always use the Find capability form the Edit menu. In fact I often do this. But it's certainly not great.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx) will search through your code and tell you what is not being used. The version for VBA can be found [here](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx).

The specific feature in MZ-Tools that performs what you asking about is [Review Source Code](http://www.mztools.com/v3/onlinehelp/index.html?html_review_source_code.htm):

> The Review Source Code feature allows
>   you to review the source code to
>   detect some unused declarations
>   (constants, variables, parameters,
>   procedures, etc.).

Comment: Yes: It is free, easy, and very efficient. Once you notice how much you save time by using it, please do like me: donate!

Comment: Unfortunately no longer free - https://www.mztools.com/v8/purchase.aspx

Comment: Version 8 is a "free 30 day trial" (with nags), but I wouldn't recommend it.  The "Dead Code Review" option in the "Review Quality" operation does check for unused variables and procedures, but returns garbage too (like the rest of the review check). Perhaps some people want to be told where to put comments and how to capitalize their variables and procedure names, I found it kind of annoying, especially given that never seen these naming conventions it's insisting upon.

Answer (score 13):

Another method (because I don't have admin privileges to install that software), is to put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. Then comment out all the `Dim`'med variables, and debug through your code with <kbd>F8</kbd> or recompile with  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>

Uncomment the `Dim`s one by one until `Option Explicit` returns no compiler errors, at which point any variables still commented out can be ignored, as they are not used in your code

---

Similar to MZ-Tools, [RubberDuck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/releases/latest) has a [VariableNotUsed Inspection](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/VariableNotUsed) (amongst many other things) that should show precisely what you're after. It's free and, as of v2.2.0.3086, it supports non-admin installation.

Comment: Stupidly simple, yet practical solution that should work in many cases (+1).