# Excel CurrentProject.Path, runime error 424

Tags: excel, vba

I have never ever done anything in VBA for excel before. I have my whole dashboard working when the .accdb is in C drive but now i want it in the same folder as excel workbook.

Im getting "Run-time error '424: Object required" for the bottom line below

```
Dim DatabasePath As String
DatabasePath = CurrentProject.Path & "\SpreadSheetData.accdb"
```

Why is this? Thanks for your help

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules. This will save you from headaches like this. [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139321/how-do-i-force-vba-access-to-require-variables-to-be-defined/1139522#1139522)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no [`CurrentProject`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080201360.aspx) in Excel. If you want to refer to the workbook in which the executing code resides, use [`ThisWorkbook`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080550372.aspx) instead.