# Merging 3 Sheets Into 1 Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want a script that pulls 3 different worksheets from another workbook and just stack the data in a new blank sheet.

This seems like it should work but it's not:

```
Sub CombineSheets()

Set NewSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set MC = Workbooks.Open("S:\OtherWorkBook.xlsm")
Set T1 = MC.Worksheets("T1")
Set T2 = MC.Worksheets("T2")
Set T3 = MC.Worksheets("T3")

With T1
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A5:I" & lastrow).Copy NewSheet.Range("A" & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
End With

With T2
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A5:I" & lastrow).Copy NewSheet.Range("A" & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
End With

With T3
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A5:I" & lastrow).Copy NewSheet.Range("A" & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
End With

Workbooks("OtherWorkBook.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

The script runs but nothing is dumped into NewSheet?  What am I missing.  Thank you!

Comment: You will save yourself a world of pain if you declare all of your variables, and force yourself to do so as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1139321/119775

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `Destination:=` after your `.Copy` call.

```
With T1
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A5:I" & lastrow).Copy Destination:=NewSheet.Range("A" & NewSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
End With
```

This worked for me. I also changed `wks` to `NewSheet`. because your code doesn't clarify what `wks` exactly is.