# Return Boolean from Function VBA

Tags: ms-access, vb6, vba

It seems pretty strange, although the code seems correct I always get back a False Boolean value for:

- AgencyNameResult = CheckLenght(AgencyName, 2)
- AgencyWebsiteResult = CheckLenght(AgencyWebsite, 5).

Could you identify the mistake?

```
Public Function CheckLenght(value As String, CharLimit As Integer) As Boolean

 Dim StringLength As Integer

 StringLength = Len(value)

 If StringLength > CharLimit Then
  CheckLength = True
 Else
  CheckLength = False
 End If

End Function

Private Sub btAddAgency_Click()

Dim AgencyName As String
Dim AgencyWebsite As String,
Dim AgencyNameResult As Boolean
Dim AgencyWebsiteResult As Boolean

Me.tbAgencyName.SetFocus
AgencyName = Me.tbAgencyName.Text
Me.tbAgencyWebsite.SetFocus
AgencyWebsite = Me.tbAgencyWebsite.Text

AgencyNameResult = CheckLenght(AgencyName, 2)
AgencyWebsiteResult = CheckLenght(AgencyWebsite, 5)

....
```

Comment: you have a type error, you Function is `CheckLenght` , and your parameter you use is `CheckLength`.

Comment: Oh my god, I should have drink that coffee. It was pretty strange. Thanks for your input!

Comment: This is a prime example why you should always use [`Option Explicit`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139321/how-do-i-force-vba-access-to-require-variables-to-be-defined) :)

Comment: I usually don't program in VBA. Thanks for showing me this option. It will save me in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is called

```
Public Function CheckLenght
```

Yet, you attempt to assign the return value to

```
  CheckLength = False
```

Solution:

rename your function to

```
Public Function CheckLength
```