# Moving tasks from the TO-Do list to an "Inquiries" Task folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to move tasks from the To-Do list to an "Inquiries" Task folder.
Preferably it should move the task without having to select it.

This code gives me:

> 'Runtime Error '424' Object Required'

Original code from https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/macro-move-folder/

```vb
Sub MoveTask()
 
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objItem As TaskItem
    Dim strSignifier As String
     
    Set objOutlook = Application
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
    Set objItem = objFolder.Items.Add(olTaskItem) ' this line has the error
    Set objDestFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks).Folders("Inquiries")
 
    strSignifier = "#CT-"
 
    If Left(Item.subject, Len(strSignifier)) = strSignifier Then
        objItem.Move objDestFolder
    End If
               
    Set objDestFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also `Dim` and `Set` `objFolder` in order to use it, or change it to `objDestFolder` or `objSourceFolder` depending on what you are trying to do.

Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and it will help detect these things.

Comment: I tried changing the code according to your suggestion, but now I don't even get a prompt to test run the macro, and the tasks also have not moved. Did I need to bind it to a ribbon button or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: @RyanLee [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50398490/edit)  your question to show your current code. You may find Option Explicit answers the question in your comment. [How do I force VBA/Access to require variables to be defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139321/how-do-i-force-vba-access-to-require-variables-to-be-defined).

Comment: My boss just got back to me and said we'll use the shared task feature in outlook instead. Thank you everyone for your help!