# Can I get Access to automatically name a file export with a variable part of the file name and a fixed part of the filename

Tags: vba, ms-access, export-to-excel

I am working on an Access 2014 DB that exports the results of a query to an excel file that can be sent to a third party.  I want the resulting excel file to go to a specified folder on a shared drive, with a naming scheme of "serialnumber vendor ASL.xlsx"

Any hints I should look at, pointers to websites that I did not find with Duck Duck Go, all would be greatly appreciated

Right now I am using a simple Macro to export the file with the "ExportWithFormatting" but I cant seem to get anything going in the "Output File" box that gives me any flexibility.

I suspect this can be done with VBS, but I'm pretty shaky when it comes to establishing and running a VBS module.  I converted the Macro to a VBS Module, but I have no idea where to go from here.

```
Option Compare Database

'------------------------------------------------------------
' expord_ASL_to_Excel
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function expord_ASL_to_Excel()
On Error GoTo expord_ASL_to_Excel_Err

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Match up", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "", True, "", , acExportQualityPrint


expord_ASL_to_Excel_Exit:
    Exit Function

expord_ASL_to_Excel_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume expord_ASL_to_Excel_Exit

End Function
```

I tinkered with it a bit, but I can't get it to do anything.  I am currently trying to backtrack through the basics of running a VBS module, so I don't need any help with that yet.  I'm just trying to figure out this little bit of finesse going.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Mike , that looks a lot better

Comment: Your code indicates Access-which is VBA, but your question indicates VBS.  Are you working in VBA?  In addition, do you want to hardcode the path of the export or would you prefer a prompt for selecting the file location (potentially with the target filename already prefilled?)

Comment: I guess I'm using VBA, whatever is a part of Access.  I'm fairly good with using all the native stuff in Access, but getting into the guts like this is where I have problems.  My end result I hope will be a fixed location followed by a target filename prefilled, but the filename will be based on the value returned in field of the query.  I could also use the value in a box on a form.  Actually, I suspect the form value might be better

Comment: So this is a bit of a multi-area issue.  I can point you in the right direction for some good reading.  If you supply a bit of info, I can block out some example code for you.  Generally, variable items like this would utilize the results of the query itself.  For that we need recordsets.  See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864160/code-to-loop-through-all-records-in-ms-access .  We can get vendor/serial from the recordset and  concat w/directory  and insert them here `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Match up", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", [FULL PATH], True, "", , acExportQualityPrint`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share recordsets because of confidentiality.  However, I have a general structure of a front form where a serial number and Vendor are put into 2 separate Unbound combo boxes.  The Query uses those two boxes as criteria for the query results, and that is what gets exported, 30 to 200 records at a time.  Can we use the values in those combo boxes to concat into the target filename?  Your code snippet makes sense, I was trying to put the path in the wrong place in my experiment.  Thanks @Mike

Comment: You bet. The combo's make it much easier.  In the place of [FULL PATH] try something like this `"C:\Your\Network\Path\" &Forms!YourFormName!YourVendorComboBoxName.Value & " " & Forms!YourFormName!YourSerialComboBoxName.Value & " ASL.xlsx"`

Comment: Do I put that in the VBA module or in the "Output File" box directly in the Macro?  Also, can you write this up as an answer so I can upvote and give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per OP's comments, Vendor and Serial are being selected from ComboBoxes on Form.

This code should be placed in the module - overwrite the function that is there.  It can be triggered via Macro - RunCode or you can link a button click directly to it.

Just replace the networkPath value with the folder (including the final ) where you want the file to end up.

Then replace the Form("Form1") and ComboBox("SerialComboBox", "VendorComboBox") designations with the names of your form and controls.

```
Function expord_ASL_to_Excel()
On Error GoTo expord_ASL_to_Excel_Err

Dim networkPath As String

networkPath = "C:\Your\Network\Path\"

exportPath = networkPath & Forms!Form1!SerialComboBox.Value & " " & Forms!Form1!VendorComboBox.Value & " ASL.xlsx"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Match up", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", exportPath, True, "", , acExportQualityPrint

expord_ASL_to_Excel_Exit:
        Exit Function

expord_ASL_to_Excel_Err:
        MsgBox Error$
        Resume expord_ASL_to_Excel_Exit
End Function
```

Comment: Some suggestion: [Option Explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1139321/9439330) on top of (every) module, declare exportPath, make networkPath  a constant (Const instead Dim), replace`Exit Sub`with`Exit Function`at exit-handler, avoid blanks in table/query names (or be forced to use square-btackets), avoid blanks in paths (filename), use underscore because with blanks they might need additional quotation. Use`vbNullString`instead of`""`to avoid accidental insert of a character and avoid underscore in method names like`expord_ASL_to_Excel`, use PascalCase instead`ExpordASLToExcel`

Answer (score 1):

This solution is very helpful to me. With little modification and it worked for me. Thank you all. I need help to apply filter to report and then use the filtered value as discipline (disc) value.

```
Function exportPDF()

On Error GoTo exportPDF_Err

   Dim Report_Names() As String
   Dim MyReport As String
   Dim networkPath As String
   Dim LDate As String
   Dim LYear As Integer
   Dim LMonth As Integer
   Dim LDay As Integer
   Dim Discipline As String

   MyExport = Reports!rptCurrentWK
   LDate = Date
   LYear = Year(LDate)
   LMonth = Month(LDate)
   LDay = Day(MyExport!WEdate)
   Disc = MyExport!Discipline.Value


   networkPath = "C:\Users\MSS\Drive\Timesheets\Access Export\"

   exportPath = networkPath & "Timesheet-" & Disc & "_WE_" & LYear & 
   "-" & LMonth & "-" & LDay & ".PDF"

  DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptCurrentWK", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", exportPath, 
  False, "", , acExportQualityPrint

   exportPDF_Exit:
    Exit Function

   exportPDF_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume exportPDF_Exit
   End Function
```